# Path Integral measure over differential forms

Tags: path-integral

Can one define a path integral over differential forms, for instance $$\int [\mathcal{D}\phi]$$ where $\phi = X_{\mu}dx^{\mu}$ a one-form and $[\mathcal{D}\phi]$ is the path-integral measure? Does such a thing make sense?

Comment: Well, there's e.g. the path integral over the EM gauge field $A$ in pure QED.

Comment: @Qmechanic But the path integral is over $A_{\mu}$ and not $A_{\mu}dx^{\mu}$.

Comment: $A_{\mu}$ is (up to mathematical nuances) the coefficient of a one-form.

Comment: @NDewolf I agree, but it is clearly not the same. I am trying to understand the path integral measure as an invariant measure in the space of differential forms.